A movie about a girl with cancer
I don’t remember much because I haven't watched it in a long time but here's parts I remember. A  girl and her boyfriend love skating and they end up finding out she has cancer. And when he visits her in the hospital he lays on her bed and the nurses tell him to leave but he stays anyways. I'm pretty sure she dies at the end. Please help I wanna watch it again. 

I think you're after The Whole of the Moon from 1997. It's about a boy and a girl who love rollerblading; the girl eventually loses her battle to cancer and the boy lies with her in her hospital bed and refuses to let go when the nurses try to pry them apart. The only thing you seemed to have skipped is that he has cancer too. It was also a book. The movie is currently available on Youtube, if you wish to verify it.

Thank you so much it was it. I haven't watched it since I was in elementary school.I always remembered the title had moon in it. A lot of people thought i was putting movies together. Thank you again

I cannot recall about skating. but its surely plot of A walk to Remember

Why surely? There's no skating there at all IIRC. Can you elaborate?

Its a wrong answer, And I mixed up plot with girl suffering from cancer ..

Well I do agree it's wrong answers , should I delete it ? Why a -1 now ?
